# How to debug terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-modules

I was trying to test running a terraform module from my company.

Then running terraform apply was giving the following error.

```
╷
│ Error: Missing required argument
│
│ The argument "domain" is required, but was not set.
```

I searched all my project folders including the files in `.terraform` folder, but I could not locate that variable.

How do I know which terraform script was giving that error?

Comment: One reason why you can end up with unattributed errors like this is if the error originates in a situation where Terraform noticed you were missing a particular block and attempted to construct one automatically, but then what Terraform generated was itself invalid. In my experience the most common example of that is provider configurations, represented as `provider` blocks.

Comment: The way I would debug this, then, is to run `terraform providers` to see all of the providers that this configuration is using, then consult the documentation for each of them to see if any of them have a required argument called `domain`. If so, the solution would be to write an explicit `provider` block to configure that provider, and then set a suitable value for `domain`.

Answer (score 8):

1. if you need enable debug in terraform, add `TF_LOG=debug` before normal terraform commands in Linux, such as

```
TF_LOG=debug terraform plan
```

2. for your issue, you miss to feed the variable value. try

```
terraform plan -var domain=xxxx
```

Comment: I got: A variable named "domain" was assigned on the command line, but the root module does not declare a variable of that name. To use this value, add a "variable" block to the configuration.

Comment: Running TF_LOG=debug in front gives TF_LOG=debug : The term 'TF_LOG=debug' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: you run in Windows or Linux/Mac? If it is Windows, change the command to Windows system, such as `set %TF_LOG%=debug` (but I am not windows expert, not sure the command is proper) , then run terraform command

Comment: Yes, I am on Windows. I set the environment variable now and I could see some debugging. But it does not help much as I still having the "domain" argument missing issue. And the debug log does not show where it was coming from

Comment: Answer worked for me What Not Worked!! is ->
`set TF_LOG=TRACE`